# Add a key value in associative array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have a variable that have a dynamic value:

`var location = 'state_name'`

I want to use it in associative array as a key just like this:

```
  array.push({
        location: value,
        ...
  });
```

It should save a key as `state_name` instead of `location`. How to do this?

Comment: What should be the value against the key `state_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` is a reserved word in JavaScript. Use some other name as variable. Try with square bracket (`[]`) which allows property names as variables:

```js
var array = [];
var loc = 'state_name';
array.push({
      [loc]: 'test'
});
console.log(array)
```

Comment: absolutely this is the answer.

Comment: @ggDeGreat, thanks and glad that it helps you:)